# Exception: Multiple service implementations found for interface DeployableContainer when running Arquillian tests

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, wildfly, jboss-arquillian, jboss-forge

I'm trying to follow the example project "Feedback" from [Continuous Enterprise Development in Java, ch. 3](https://github.com/arquillian/continuous-enterprise-development/blob/master/ch03.asciidoc) with a bit of modification.

I am using IntelliJ Idea and its JBoss-Forge plugin which shouldn't differ from using the console like in the book.

So far I've created a new project with the following characteristics:

- Java 1.8
- JEE 7
- Wildfly 10.1.0.Final
- JUnit 4.12
- Arquillian 1.1.13.0
- Hibernate
- Maven profile: arquillian-wildfly-remote

I've followed every step from the tutorial, all using the IntelliJ plugin:

- set ACCEPT_DEFAULTS true
- created the project
- set up persistence with Hibernate
- set up validation with Hibernate validator
- created entity FeedbackEntry
- scaffolded the UI
- forge install-plugin arquillian
- set up Arquillian with Wildfly remote container
- created an Arquillian
- built and deploy the app

All of them ended successfully, I can open the UI and store some values in the DB. The problem comes when trying to run the test: I create an *Wildfly Remote* Arquillian container:

[image: Creating arquillian container]

[image]

After clicking OK this is the stacktrace I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not create new instance of class org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor

    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:166)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.build(TestRunnerAdaptorBuilder.java:52)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:114)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.spi.SecurityActions.newInstance(SecurityActions.java:162)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.ContainerCreationException: Could not create Container arquillian-wildfly-remote
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.client.container.ContainerRegistryCreator.createRegistry(ContainerRegistryCreator.java:78)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.bindAndFire(ManagerImpl.java:263)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.InstanceImpl.set(InstanceImpl.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.config.impl.extension.ConfigurationRegistrar.loadConfiguration(ConfigurationRegistrar.java:73)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:96)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:85)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:143)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:114)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.start(ManagerImpl.java:288)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.<init>(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:63)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Multiple service implementations found for interface org.jboss.arquillian.container.spi.client.container.DeployableContainer. org.jboss.as.arquillian.container.remote.RemoteDeployableContainer, org.arquillian.container.chameleon.ChameleonContainer
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.loadable.ServiceRegistryLoader.onlyOne(ServiceRegistryLoader.java:74)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.impl.LocalContainerRegistry.create(LocalContainerRegistry.java:76)
    ... 37 more


Test ignored.

Test ignored.

Process finished with exit code 255
```

I've searched in many places and I only have found [this](https://developer.jboss.org/message/638631#638631). However I don't think I have more than 1 container, only Wildfly, so I'm completely clueless about this.

Pom and other key files here: https://gist.github.com/josemigallas/a139fc601b022356391fad5b2ec588b0

**Why is this failing and how can I solve/workaround this issue?**

Answer (score 1):

From my experience, it might be an issue with Arquillian Plugin or IDEA Maven support having troubles with activating the profile. Please make sure that `arquillian-wildfly-remote` is in fact enabled by default (if it's ticked then untick and tick it again :)). Also run the test using regular JUnit runner, not the Arquillian one.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem when using IntelliJ with Arquillian support. Can you try to run it from CLI?